# In this cylindrical tank, by how much will the level of the water rise?

Tags: geometry

there. In the following picture is a puzzling question from a primary school math exercise booklet for selective high school exams in Australia. I don't think enough information is provided to solve this question but there may be something I missed out. Thank you for your help.
[image]

Comment: It looks like this is a follow-on from another question. What do you already know about "this prism"?

Comment: Thank you, hexomino. Yes, this question is a sequel of another question, in which the volume of the prism is given. Sorry for not providing the whole piciture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The water level would rise by $\dfrac{\text{volume of prism}}{25.5}$, due to [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle). But as we don't know the dimensions of the prism, so we don't know it's volume, and so we cannot determine the answer.

Comment: Thank you, JMP. I've tried to calculate the largest possible area of the base of the prism in the cylindrical container but I still can't find the height of the prism. So, I assumed the two sideways sides are squares but later things don't add up in relation to the choices provided. Later I found out that this question is a sequel of a previous question and then everything came to light. Sorry for not presenting the whole picture.